# Proof - Set of all subsets of a finite set $\Omega$, $2^\Omega$, is also finite

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

As the title implies, I am asked to show that the set of all subsets of some finite set $\Omega$, $2^\Omega$, is also finite. However, I am not really sure if the proof that I've come up with is entirely correct.

This is what I have:

Since $\Omega$ is finite, then $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that we can construct a bijection from the finite set of integers $\{x \in \mathbb{Z}_+ | x \leq n\}$ to every element of $\Omega$.

Furthermore, since $2^\Omega$ is the set of all subsets of $\Omega$, then the total number of such sets is $q = 2^n < \infty$. Therefore, we can construct a bijection from the finite set of integers $\{ x \in \mathbb{Z}_+ | x \leq q \}$ to every element of $2^\Omega$.

$\square$

I would appreciate any corrections or comments.

Comment: This is one of those proofs where I feel like the conclusion is frustratingly obvious, but I think you've done a nice job of formalizing it. The specific details at this level will depend on how rigid your instructor wants to be, but I say you've got it, personally.

Comment: In most settings you should probably use induction on the size of $\Omega$.

Comment: @TheCount I disagree, the proof is circular.

Comment: @palmpo: yes, the very detail-minded would argue this, and I see the merit of it. it depends what order you learn things in, i suppose.

Comment: You also might prove that, for any finite sets $X$ and $Y$, the set of all maps from $X$ to $Y$ is finite and has cardinal equal to $|Y|^{|X|}$, then show there's a bijection between $\mathscr P(\Omega)$ and the set of all maps from $\omega$ to the set $\{0,1\}$ via the characteristic functions of subsets.

Answer (score 4):

> Furthermore, since $2^\Omega$ is the set of all subsets of $\Omega$, then the total number of such sets is $q=2^n$

Well if you already knew this, you're done!

Remember that $X$ is finite iff there is some bijection $f:[n]\to X$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $[n]=\{0,\dotsc,n-1\}$. So that statement implies $2^\Omega$ is finite.

But if you didn't already know $\lvert2^\Omega\rvert=2^{\lvert\Omega\rvert}$ for $\Omega$ finite, then you should prove this by induction on $\Omega$. This is partially the reason we use the notation $2^X$ instead of $P(X)$ for the power set of $X$.

Comment: Thank you. I see, sometimes "less is more". Unfortunately, I can't give you an upvote due to my lack of reputation.

Comment: Try again.  You now should have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** If $a\in\Omega$, then $P(\Omega)=P(\Omega\setminus\{a\})\cup \{\,x\in P(\Omega)\mid a\in x\,\}$ and $x\mapsto x\cup\{a\}$ is a bijection from the first to the second set. Now use induction on $|\Omega|$ and that the union of two finite sets is finite.